# Why do I get "unable to connect a socket" when I try to clone via a git URL?

Tags: git, github

When I try to clone a project from the GitHub, it gives me the following error.

```
:git clone git://github.com/project.git
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
```

But if I use the corresponding HTTP URL, it's fine:

```
:git clone http://github.com/project.git
```

What should I to do to clone through a git URL?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like there is a network problem because the git protocol, by default, uses the port 9418. Looks like your traffic is blocked on that port.

Comment: Unfortunately, this happens a lot in workplaces. As long as the http clone works, you pretty much have to count yourself lucky you got through at all and move on.

Comment: And blame your network admin for using a TCP RST (misleading) over a ICMP Administrative Prohibited.

Comment: If you have netcat installed you can use it to verify that you cannot connect to github on that port: nc github.com 9418 -v

Comment: That's rather bizarre.  I've totally been using git protocol URLs on a machine behind my firewall (that I administer) and it had been working fine until today.

Answer (score 72):

Uku Loskit is right about the port being blocked. The solution is to set up your remote's URL without using `git://`

I use: `https://github.com/user/project.git` or `git@github.com:user/project.git`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is because port 9418 is blocked.
If you have directadmin, open port 9418 in csf firewall and restart it.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in your answer.