# Ruby bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, forem

I'm trying to install forem on my server, and i'm getting this error when I run `bundle install`:

```
Fetching git://github.com/radar/forem.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused

Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/radar/forem.git' "/home/box1/.bundler/cache/git/forem-8662403862ddafa624baa2b55484281b10db048e" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /home/box1/rails_apps/forem has failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning using HTTP and not SSH:

```
git clone https://github.com/radar/forem.git
```

[See answer and comments to similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015732/why-do-i-get-unable-to-connect-a-socket-when-i-try-to-clone-via-a-git-url)