# can't fetch active admin from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, activeadmin

Trying to use active admin for rails 4.1 and getting error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection refused
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe this applies to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015732/why-do-i-get-unable-to-connect-a-socket-when-i-try-to-clone-via-a-git-url

Comment: @rkon please add as answer and I'll mark it correct. Thank You

Comment: `gem 'activeadmin', :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented this is probably a network issue - most likely something blocking the git protocol altogether.

More information and workarounds here [Why do I get "unable to connect a socket" when I try to clone via a git URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015732/why-do-i-get-unable-to-connect-a-socket-when-i-try-to-clone-via-a-git-url)